# How to get RGB color codes from an image and making them array?

Tags: python, arduino

Before asking a question I want to show my Python code which I'm using for reading Excel cells where I'm drawing whatever I want and preparing Excel cells for arduino codes to light on 32x92pixel tower.

```
    import xlrd
    ExcelFileName= 'data.xlsx'
    workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(ExcelFileName) 
    worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name("Sheet1")
#inside of the data.xlsx file I create 39 row and 31 column and this where I'm #drawing what I want to light up.

    num_rows = worksheet.nrows #Number of Rows
    num_cols = worksheet.ncols #Number of Columns

    x=0  #for x line
    y=0  #for y line
    floors=-1
    rooms=-1

    def cell(y,x):  #for getting values from each cells

        return worksheet.cell_value(y, x) # Read the data in the current cell

    #this is tower model and every floor has 92 addressable rgb leds.And there is 30 floors.Each 10 floor has different data cable so 1 data line controls 920 rgb.

    #On arduino I have macro which is "#define LEDNO(FLOOR, ROOM) ((ROOM) + (FLOOR*92))" this.So if I write floor and room number I will get number of led.Because all strip connect to each other.
    #First floor data connected from "right bottom corner",this is my start point for leds.And I'm reading excel cells so I have to start to reading from right bottom corner to have in order for my leds.

    for i in range(30,20,-1):
        y=i
        floors+=1
        for j in range(38,0,-1):
            x=j
            rooms+=1
            if rooms>37:
                rooms=0
            print("leds[LEDNO(" + str(floors) + "," + str(rooms) +")].setRGB(" + str(cell(y,x)) + ");")

    #for next 10 floor rooms should start from -1 again.
    rooms=-1
    for i in range(20,10,-1):

        y=i
        floors+=1
        for j in range(38,0,-1):
            x=j
            rooms+=1
            if rooms>37:
                rooms=0
            print("leds2[LEDNO(" + str(floors) + "," + str(rooms) +")].setRGB(" + str(cell(y,x)) + ");")

    rooms=-1
    for i in range(10,0,-1):
        y=i
        floors+=1
        for j in range(38,0,-1):
            x=j
            rooms+=1
            if rooms>37:
                rooms=0
            print("leds3[LEDNO(" + str(floors) + "," + str(rooms) +")].setRGB(" + str(cell(y,x)) + ");")
```

**Question:** How can I get RGB codes from an image with Python? And is it possible to convert this RGB codes for 30x92 pixel? Atleast I need to read and print given image pixels.

I need to get RGB color codes from image same as what I did on excel.I don't know if its possible with Python or not.

Comment: Where does the image come from? Where is it?

Comment: inside of the pycharm project file.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use scipy to read the image as a (30,92,3) numpy array (possibly ,4 for the last one, depending on the file that you are not showing), then assign the value as you want:

```
img[i, j, :] = RGBvalue
```

Comment: yes, depends if it's RGB or RGBA (in which case you should do img[i,j,:3])

Comment: okay,I'm beginner on python I havent use scipy before,I will obligate it and try to make it,thank you :)

Comment: I couldnt figure out scipy from tutorials.Could you show me reading given image with scipy?

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imread.html to read the image

Comment: to make with this way I need to install PIL lib also,but PIL not supporting Python 3 yet.Am I able to do what I want with only scipy lib?

Comment: Indeed PIL is abandoned, use Pillow instead: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.3.x/

Comment: I install the Pillow,but I couldnt make their tutorial example which at gifthub:https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.18.1/scipy/misc/pilutil.py#L103-L155